# AngularJS uppercase inside the ng-if directive

Tags: angularjs

Why below one is not working ? I need to convert the `IsValue` into uppercase value and then need to check it with the `NO` value.How can I do that ?

```
   <td class="red-color" ng-if="item.IsValue | uppercase == 'NO'">{{item.IsValue}}</td>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure the `uppercase` filter is applied (using `()`) before comparing the value:

```
<td class="red-color" ng-if="(item.IsValue | uppercase) == 'NO'">{{item.IsValue}}</td>
```

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5m2AL1soJLA46Lc68xwQ?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks.'()' is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to check for a value and then display it in uppercase somewhere (?) so this will get you going:
the ng-if will just check the value. If it is "test" it will display it as uppercase.

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p class="red-color" ng-if="item.IsValue == 'test'">{{item.IsValue | uppercase}}</p>
  <input ng-model="item.IsValue" type="text">
 </div>
```

js

```
 function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.item = {IsValue: 'UpPerCASE'};
 }
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7rzeLot/)

the string comparison is case sensitive so if what you want is to convert it and then compare, you would string.[toUppeCcase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) it or use the [angular method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.uppercase)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS accepts any word value starting with 'n' or 'N' as false. You don't need to convert uppercase and check the value if your model value varies 'no', 'yes'.

```
<td class="red-color" ng-if="item.IsValue">{{item.IsValue}}</td>
```

might simply work in many use cases.